# How to share a value between the components in angular 7

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

I have many components in my angular 7 project.Tired to share a value between the components but not working.I have given my code below.Anyone know the way please help to find the solution.

Folders: 
My components:

```
app ->

   ->power
   ->air
   ->pollution
   ->wind
```

power.component.ts:

```
@Output() public globalValue= new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit(){

 this.globalValue.emit('helloworld');

}
```

air.component.ts:

```
@Input() globalValue: string;

ngOnInit(){

console.log(this.globalValue); //Output should be helloworld

}
```

pollution.component.ts:

```
@Input() globalValue: string;

ngOnInit(){

console.log(this.globalValue); //Output should be helloworld

}
```

wind.component.ts:

```
@Input() globalValue: string;

ngOnInit(){

console.log(this.globalValue); //Output should be helloworld

}
```

Comment: Don't use input or output it's only valid between parent and child components. Just set your variable on the service and inject your service in the constructor of your component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provide many ways by which we can share values between components.

https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

But as I can see you want to share with multiple components. You can create a service and then any component can subscribe to it and will receive value.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalService{

  // Observable string sources
  private globalValueSource = new Subject<string>();


  // Observable string streams
  globalValueAnnounced$ = this.globalValueSource.asObservable();

  // Service message commands
  sendGlobalValue(value: string) {
    this.globalValueSource.next(value);
  }

}
```

In any of your components, you can get the value by subscribing to it like:

```
constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
    globalService.globalValueAnnounced$.subscribe(
      value => {
       console.log(value);
      });
  }
```